# SQL not include field ID which includes following

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am reading data from 3 tables

ID is common between all 3 tables.

**This works**

```
select 

        T1.ID,
        T2.CAUSE_NO,
        T2.CAUSE_TYPE,
        T3.START_NO,
        T3.START_TYPE,
        T1.Comments
from    Table1 T1,
        Table2 T2,
        Table3 T3

where   T2.ID = T3.ID 
    and T1.ID = T2.ID 
    AND T2.CAUSE_NO NOT IN (64,8,43,63,65)
```

I also need to add condition where I don't want to Include ID `where CAUSE_NO = 13 and START_NO = 83.`

below is sample table. green is what I want end result and red rows should not be included.
[image]
Can someone help add this condition.

Comment: From the question it seems that you need to add the condition `AND (CAUSE_NO <> 13 or START_NO <> 83)` but can't understand your sample table...

Comment: I believe that worked. Thanks a lot. in sample table I do not want to include ID = 12, 15,19,24,27 because it contains 13 & 83 together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this `where` clause:

```
where   T2.ID = T3.ID 
    and T1.ID = T2.ID 
    AND T2.CAUSE_NO NOT IN (64,8,43,63,65)
    AND not (CAUSE_NO = 13 and START_NO = 83)
```

You should also learn to use ANSI standard join syntax.

Comment: condition is it same as `AND (CAUSE_NO <> 13 or START_NO <> 83)`?

Comment: No I tried that, it is doing opposite, it is only showing 13 & 83 records.

Comment: It should be the same, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), have you noticed the `not` after the `AND` ?

Comment: @Mowgli . . . I think the version with "not" is a better way of expressing the logic in your question.

Comment: Can you please help me, do you know why it skips null if I use `and T1.Comments not like '%something' and T1.Comments not like '%abc%'`

Comment: @Mowgli . . . NULL in a comparison always translates to FALSE, with the one exception of `is NULL`.  So, `NULL like '%something'` is FALSE and `NULL not like `%something`' is false too.  Try doing something like `coalesce(t1.comments, '') like '%something'` or '(t1.comments like '%something' or t1.comments is null`.